# firebase data validation failing

Tags: validation, firebase, rules

First time working with Firebase on a new project and I'm getting a permission denied message when writing an activity event when I include a validation rule.

The validation rule looks like:

```
"activity": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null",
".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user'])",
".indexOn": ["when"]
}
```

On a new activity event, I push a new entry, grab the token ID and make it (for now) part of the data being pushed.  When watching this in debug (using a custom token authentication system) this is what I see.  The json pushed has a "user" entry that is the GUID of the auth user so I'm not sure why it's failing.  I spaced out the json text.

```
utility.js (line 1675)
FIREBASE: Attempt to write {
"id":"-K4oomuOpaY4K2aGUYZA",
"imp":false,
"text":"xxx.",
**"user":"0648480c-xxx"**,
"when":1449363973059
} to /activity/## with auth={"uid":"0648480c-xxx","name":"Greg Merideth"}

/activity:.write: "auth != null" => true
/activity:.validate: "newData.hasChildren(['user'])" => false

FIREBASE: Validation failed. firebase.js (line 195)
FIREBASE: Write was denied firebase.js (line 195)
```

I even tried changing the rule to ".validate": "newData.hasChild('user')" with the same end result.

Is newData looking at the inbound packet or my "auth" packet?

*Update (from the comments)*

The addition of a new item calls a function passing in the fbActivity handler which then calls:

```
var message = fbActivity.push({
  id: user.fn(), 
  text: t.val(), 
  imp: false, 
  user: user.uid(), 
  when: new Date().getTime()}
```

To push the new entry. We're not using the fb.timestamp as our server runs 3 seconds behind fb's so our time stamps come out weird.

Comment: Cross post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/a53ya-tVf80

Comment: I added the most likely answer below. If that is not it, please add the code that you use to write the data. Without that it'll be impossible to be certain what's wrong.

Comment: The addition of a new item calls a function passing in the fbActivity handler which then calls:

var message = fbActivity.push({id: user.fn(), text: t.val(), imp: false, user: user.uid(), when: new Date().getTime()}

To push the new entry.  We're not using the fb.timestamp as our server runs 3 seconds behind fb's so our time stamps come out weird.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're calling `push()` to add a new child under `activity`. In that case, your rules are missing the extra level that is generated by `push()`:

```
"activity": {
  "$activityid": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['user'])",
    ".indexOn": ["when"]
  }
}
```

If that is the case, please take time to read the [Firebase security guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/index.html), which explains this and many other useful bits about the language.

Comment: With that format I was getting read deny messages.  I'm thinking the way in which I'm passing in activity feed messages may need tweaking.  Moving the ".read" and ".indexon" up a tier worked while still triggering validate.